# How to extract values from key value map?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, dictionary, apache-spark-sql

I have a column of type map, where the key and value changes. I am trying to extract the value and create a new column.

Input:

```
----------------+
|symbols        |
+---------------+
|[3pea -> 3PEA] |
|[barello -> BA]|
|[]             |
|[]             |
+---------------+
```

Expected output:

```
--------+
|symbols|
+-------+
|3PEA   |
|BA     |
|       |
|       |
+-------+
```

Here is what I tried so far using a `udf`:

```scala
def map_value=udf((inputMap:Map[String,String])=> {inputMap.map(x=>x._2) 
      })
```

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[String] is not supported

Comment: Can you show the def / structure of the DF ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._
val m = Seq(Array("A -> abc"), Array("B -> 0.11856755943424617"), Array("C -> kqcams"))

val df = m.toDF("map_data")
df.show
// Simulate your data I think.

val df2 = df.withColumn("xxx", split(concat_ws("",$"map_data"), "-> ")).select($"xxx".getItem(1).as("map_val")).drop("xxx")
df2.show(false)
```

results in:

```
+--------------------+
|            map_data|
+--------------------+
|          [A -> abc]|
|[B -> 0.118567559...|
|       [C -> kqcams]|
+--------------------+

+-------------------+
|map_val            |
+-------------------+
|abc                |
|0.11856755943424617|
|kqcams             |
+-------------------+
```

Comment: I think your answer is correct, I ended up using an udf like this def map_value=udf((inputMap:Map[String,String])=> {inputMap.map(x=>x._2).toArray.mkString })

Comment: Also fine. Cheers

Comment: Thats why I inquired how is your input.

Answer (score 3):

Since Spark [scala v2.3 api](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@map_values(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column), [sql v2.3 api](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/#map_values), or [pyspark v2.4 api](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.map_values) you can use the spark sql function `map_values`

The following is in pyspark, scala would be very similar.
Setup (assuming working SparkSession as `spark`):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = (
    spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(["""[
        {"key": ["3pea"],    "value": ["3PEA"] },
        {"key": ["barello"], "value": ["BA"]   }
    ]"""]))
    .select(F.map_from_arrays(F.col("key"), F.col("value")).alias("symbols") )
)

df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

```
root
 |-- symbols: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)

+---------------+
|        symbols|
+---------------+
| [3pea -> 3PEA]|
|[barello -> BA]|
+---------------+
```

```py
df.select((F.map_values(F.col("symbols"))[0]).alias("map_vals")).show()
```

```
+--------+
|map_vals|
+--------+
|    3PEA|
|      BA|
+--------+
```